# System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes loses first two bytes from each string

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, text, arrays

I'm attempting to turn the body of an email from Exchange Web Services email into a byte array, but every time I do this, I'm missing the first two characters of the text after inserting it into an SQL database field with the type of `image`

```
byte[] emBodyBytes;

foreach (Item item in findResults)
{
 if (item is EmailMessage)
 {
   EmailMessage em = item as EmailMessage;
   emBodyBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(em.Body.Text.ToString());

   dEmailMessage thisMailMessage = new dEmailMessage  //LINQ-to-SQL
   {
    emmMessage = emBodyBytes   //This is our byte object of the email body string
   }
   emailDB.dEmailMessages.InsertOnSubmit(thisMailMessage);
  }
}
```

So `The quick brown fox` becomes `e quick brown fox` when it's inserted into the SQL `image` field.

Where I'm a bit lost is if it's something happening during the conversion process, or if SQL is expecting leading two bytes for a field with an `image` definition.

The definition of the field is

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dEmailMessages](
    [emmMessage] [image] NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: Storing text as `image` is... counter-intuitive. Have you considered storing the text as text?

Comment: @dtb - this software is a candidate for http://www.thedailywtf.com - and it's wayyy too much work to change the SQL schema unfortunately.

Comment: does it matter what the 2 characters are?  Are they chopped off regardless of what they are?

Comment: @SteveDanner - as far as I can tell, it's always the first two, without regard to what they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe immediately after the System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes call, add something like :

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("c:\\SomeFile.txt", emBodyBytes)
```

then have a look at the generated file in a hex viewer. See if the missing two bytes are there at that stage. At least this allows you to verify if the GetBytes call is behaving as you expect it to.

Comment: Ahah, it turns out that it's not `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes` at all as it's coming out correctly. And what I'm seeing in that file is the same as what I'm seeing in the SQL Profiler as it inserts the data, so it's not a LINQ-to-SQL problem. Something is going wrong *inside* SQL, which is a totally different issue (just not one I expected). Thanks.

Comment: Are there any triggers on the table being inserted into ? Perhaps there is a funky trigger doing weird stuff, like removing the first two bytes. You'd think it unlikely, but just something to eliminate.

Comment: I've no idea, seeing as it's being written as far as I can tell correctly into the SQL table, I have to work with our DB guys (or perhaps it's the code that displays the output?)

Answer (score 0):

The essential code points are missing. I'd recommend to simplify by abandoning LINQ to SQL and writing out the SELECT statement and walking the reader and see if that helps. It may not but will make diagnostic easier.

Comment: I guess I can run the SQL profiler and watch the command that LINQ builds as a quick way of checking it.